# retryTemplate.execute not getting called

Tags: java, javabeans, spring-retry

I am using retry template as below for an exception that might occur. The retryTemplate.execute block never gets called. I have defined the retrytemplate bean as below. Not sure if that's the correct way. I am new to java and spring. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class checkUser{ 
    
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate;
        

      public checkUser(){}

      public checkUser(RetryTemplate retryTemplate){

       this.retryTemplate = retryTemplate;}
    

     private RetryTemplate retryConfig()  {
    
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
            fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000l);
            retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    
    
            SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
            retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
            retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    
            return retryTemplate;
    
        }
    
    private void checkGroup() throws Exception {
            retryTemplate = retryConfig();
           
            try {
    
                retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext retryContext) throws Exception {
                        if (retryContext.getRetryCount() < 2) { // unexpected disconnection
                            throw new RuntimeException("retry exception");
    
                        }
    
                      //do something
    
    
                        }
    
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

defined bean as below:

```
<bean id="checkUser"
          class="com.checkUser">

        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${retryTemplate}" />
        
    </bean>

    <bean id = "retryTemplate" class="com.checkUser">

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring beans are completely passive; the execute won't be called until something calls `checkGroup()`.

You should also not call `retryConfig()` for each call, that will simply overwrite the one passed into the constructor.

Your XML configuration makes no sense at all.

You need `<constructor-arg ref="templateBean"/>` where `templateBean` is a bean of type `RetryTemplate`.